# Is there a way to customize Activity Type screens?

Tags: activities, custom-templates

Trying to customize individual Activity Type displays but couldn't find any info on the proper procedure.

I'd like to hide certain fields from certain activity types. For instance, for our food bank activity, I'd like to have the end user enter only the date and names of all households that came. I can't use a profile or a webform because we may have 100 families that use the pantry that day so we are trying to set it up for one activity per day with multiple households. This activity has no need for follow-up, assignees, etc.

I have custom templates up and running and can successfully alter the basic Activity display but would like to get control of each individual type.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've handled this with a .extra.tpl file with some jQuery in it. I also used a template override for one or two customizations, but shied away from them because of the overhead of upgrading them. However, the project in question was in many ways a customized activity form, so I went ahead and did it.